# Question Contest Ideas?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

As most of you meta-heads know, RPG.SE does pretty well in terms of visits, and we're excellent about answering questions.  What we've always been a little weak on is the volume of questions.  Many other SE sites have used question contests to increase volume and help bring in new users.

What are your suggestions for a Question contest?

- What should be the theme?
- What should be the prize(s)?
- What should the question criteria be (upvotes, etc)?

---

Examples:

- [League of Legends Contest! (Gaming)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4253/121)
- [Ask Different iPad Contest](http://thenewipadishere.com/) [(meta.askdifferent)](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/the-new-ipad-is-here-ask-different-and-win-one)
- [Topic of the Week Contest (Science Fiction and Fantasy)](http://Topic%20of%20the%20Week%20Contest)

Comment: Ideas in [this chat thread](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/question-contest-discussion).  Always happy to discuss ideas at the [Game Table](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/the-game-table)!

Comment: Any chance of a link to successful question contests, so we can see what a good one looks like?

Comment: @Jadasc I updated.  If you want *even more* you can see [this filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/38499/allsecontests).

Comment: How would you prevent those contents from becoming nothing more than a massive question seeding (just asking questions for the sake of asking in order to qualify for the prices)? Or did the site's stance on question seeding change?

Comment: @arotter If you have lots of real questions to ask, go ahead.  We don't want people making up questions with no real value.  Most of the contests have upvote requirements and the like to help differentiate the real and good from the fake and seedy.

Comment: @C.Ross: I'd have dozens of questions I could ask about systems I don't currently run or play without them being "real" questions in the sense that I need the answer for any of my games. Theorycrafting and rules interpretation goes a long way, and one can always prefix the question with *"In one of my recent games..."*.

Comment: @arotter From your brief description I think those questions would probably be just fine.

Answer (score 5):

As a suggestion for prizes, how about gift-cert value at [DriveThruRPG/RPGNow](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/)? Has the advantages of being directly related to our topic of choice, encouraging purchase of RPG material, and moving the subject of questions away from the D&D family of games, which get their fair share of questions already.

Comment: Along the same lines, probably anything available on Amazon and relevant to RPGs (e.g. some RPG rules book or module) would work.