# The first annual RPG Games-fest! (Proposed Rules)

Tags: discussion

Inspired by [cleanupathon](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/clean-up-a-thon-contest), taken from highest upvoted answers [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/one-year-anniversary-contest/2830?noredirect=1#comment5308_2830).
This post shall be for rules and discussion related to the first contest. This intro bit will be cleaned up after we start.

## The RPG Stack is about to celebrate its first birthday and we want to give you presents!

[image: "Young Witerich" by Cybele Wong, thecybil.deviantart.com]

<sup>(Image by [Cybele Wong](http://thecybil.deviantart.com/art/Young-Witerich-287776396), Used with permission)</sup>

### But first, some rules...

The site has grown very well from its public launch, but we can do better. Our unanswered rate is fantastic, but we do seem to cluster around a few central themes.

Thus, the point of this contest is to diversify our answers and promote the site!

This contest will run from 29 April to 31 May.

At the end of the month, we will give prizes (to be determined), based on the people who have the most points.

- 1 point for each Announcer badge gained during the month, (don't forget to use the url from "share" to qualify for this)
- 3 points for each Booster badge gained during the month.
- 5 points for each Publicist badge gained during the month.
- 2 points for each nice answer or nice question earned during the month on the following tags (or for new systems not in the list and not merged with an existing tag) (This list was chosen by looking at the total counts of each tags and excluding systems with over 150 questions, then a bit of cleaning). 
  [13th-age](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/13th-age) [7th-sea](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7th-sea) [a-game-of-thrones](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-game-of-thrones) [adnd](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adnd) [adnd-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adnd-2e) [adventurer-conqueror-king](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventurer-conqueror-king) [all-flesh-must-be-eaten](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/all-flesh-must-be-eaten) [anima-beyond-fantasy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anima-beyond-fantasy) [apocalypse-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse-world) [ars-magica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ars-magica) [ars-magica-5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ars-magica-5) [basic-role-playing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic-role-playing) [battlestar-galactica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica) [battletech](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battletech) [black-crusade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-crusade) [buck-rogers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buck-rogers) [burning-wheel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burning-wheel) [cadillacs-and-dinosaurs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cadillacs-and-dinosaurs) [call-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu) [call-of-cthulhu-d20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu-d20) [changeling-dreaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changeling-dreaming) [changeling-lost](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changeling-lost) [coda](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coda) [continuum](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuum) [cortex](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cortex) [cortex-plus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cortex-plus) [cyberpunk-2020](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyberpunk-2020) [d20-modern](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d20-modern) [d6-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d6-system) [dangerous-journeys](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dangerous-journeys) [dark-ages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-ages) [dark-heresy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-heresy) [deadlands](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadlands) [deathwatch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathwatch) [delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green) [diaspora](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diaspora) [dictionary-of-mu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary-of-mu) [dnd-becmi](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-becmi) [dnd-bx](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-bx) [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) [dogs-in-the-vineyard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs-in-the-vineyard) [dread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dread) [dresden-files](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files) [dungeon-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-world) [earthdawn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthdawn) [eclipse-phase](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-phase) [en-garde](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/en-garde) [exalted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted) [fallout-pnp-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-pnp-rpg) [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) [fear-itself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fear-itself) [fiasco](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiasco) [freemarket](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freemarket) [fudge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fudge) [gamma-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-world) [geist-sin-eaters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geist-sin-eaters) [genius-transgression](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genius-transgression) [golarion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golarion) [gumshoe](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gumshoe) [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e) [heavygear](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heavygear) [heresy-engine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heresy-engine) [hero-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hero-system) [heroquest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroquest) [hollow-earth-expedition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollow-earth-expedition) [hunter-vigil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hunter-vigil) [in-a-wicked-age](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-a-wicked-age) [in-nomine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-nomine) [interface-zero](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface-zero) [jade-regent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jade-regent) [kult](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kult) [l5r](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r) [l5r-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r-4e) [labyrinth-lord](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labyrinth-lord) [lady-blackbird](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lady-blackbird) [laundry](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laundry) [legend](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend) [legends-of-anglerre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legends-of-anglerre) [leverage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leverage) [little-fears](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-fears) [lotfp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotfp) [mage-ascension](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-ascension) [mage-awakening](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-awakening) [maid](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maid) [marvel-heroic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-heroic) [mazes-and-minotaurs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes-and-minotaurs) [mechwarrior-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechwarrior-4e) [microscope](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microscope) [mini-six](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini-six) [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) [mutant-city-blues](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutant-city-blues) [mutants-and-masterminds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds) [natural-weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-weapon) [nobilis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nobilis) [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod) [odnd](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odnd) [over-the-edge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/over-the-edge) [palladium-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palladium-system) [paranoia](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paranoia) [reign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reign) [rogue-trader](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-trader) [rolemaster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster) [runequest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runequest) [savage-worlds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savage-worlds) [savage-worlds-fantasy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savage-worlds-fantasy) [serenity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serenity) [shadowrun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun) [shadowrun-sr4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-sr4) [shock](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shock) [sifrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sifrp) [spirit-of-the-century](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirit-of-the-century) [spycraft](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spycraft) [star-trek](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) [star-wars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) [star-wars-d20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-d20) [star-wars-saga-edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-saga-edition) [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system) [storytelling-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storytelling-system) [sword-noir](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-noir) [tekumel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tekumel) [tftfv](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tftfv) [the-dark-eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye) [the-esoterrorists](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-esoterrorists) [the-multiverse-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-multiverse-rpg) [the-one-ring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring) [the-riddle-of-steel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-riddle-of-steel) [tolkien](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) [torg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torg) [toward-one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toward-one) [trail-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trail-of-cthulhu) [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) [tremulus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tremulus) [tsoy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsoy) [ubiquity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubiquity) [unisystem](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unisystem) [universalis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universalis) [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) [vampire-masquerade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-masquerade) [vampire-requiem](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-requiem) [warp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warp) [werewolf-forsaken](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf-forsaken) [wfrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp) [wfrp-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-1e) [wfrp-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-2e) [wfrp-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-3e) [wh40k](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wh40k) [wild-talents](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wild-talents) [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness) [wraith-oblivion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wraith-oblivion) [wraith-orpheus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wraith-orpheus)

The prize pool will be Site Swag, RPG books or PDFs chosen by the moderators as a function of what tags the winners have contributed to.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Once you all have a good idea of what your event will look like (i.e. this post has some degree of community consensus) then SE (er, that is, my team and I) reviews the proposal and sets the start time. You all, however, have to pick a duration.

Comment: Would question seeding be acceptable in this contest? I'm particularly thinking of questions that I know come up a lot in a particular system that I know the answer to, but they may not have been asked on this site before.

Comment: @Phil, "question seeding" is not a problem (in general, or specific to this contest) so long as it represents a real problem that you have had with a game. I would encourage you to wait at least a day before providing an answer, however. Just make sure it's a real question that can have a real answer and has presented a problem to you.

Comment: Can we offer incentives? Like, "I'll place a bounty on the first X questions for the Thus & So RPG with a score above 5?"

Comment: I encourage members to certainly place bounties, but mods cannot award rep outside of normal means. With that said, I probably will drop bounties on my Ars Magica questions.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton That's precisely what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Why was the date changed without notice? It was April 15-May 15th, so on April 15th, I had started participating by asking questions with tags from the list. Now, the date has been pushed to April 29th-May 29th, which I'm guessing means that my contributions to the contest don't count.

Comment: Because the admins on stack exchange set those dates to the dates they chose, to give us time to properly promote the contest. You will also note that the *proposed rules* have changed slightly.

Comment: Wasn't this change made after April 15th though? I'm rather disappointed that the questions I'd asked won't count towards this, even though the rules as they were written at the time said they would count. Perhaps we could accept contributions between April 15th and the time that the rules were changed declaring it would be starting on April 29th?