# What's the status of the birthday contest?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Has the drawing been held for the [one year anniversary contest](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/one-year-anniversary-contest)? If so, who were the winners?

Comment: We're working on it.

Comment: Thanks. The radio silence just made me wonder what was going on.

Comment: Not intentional, sorry. Just the usual delays.

Comment: No worries, of course. I'm always looking for another angle to take in publicizing RPG Stack Exchange, and this should be a particularly good one.

Comment: Contest over, winners given goodies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're running a little behind at the moment.  We hope to announce the results and the winners *soon*, certainly by the end of this week.

Comment: Hi there. As the SE representative now overseeing the contest, I'd like to add confirmation to this answer. Had a bit of a rough start of the week but I'll be working with the moderators to work on announcing the results soon indeed.

Answer (score 2):

A little update on this.

So, I met with the mods and we were planning to do a little surprise ceremony for this. We'd jump into chat during an active time, and rather than having drawn the winners and announce them, we were going to do a public drawing, using our chat dice system. It seemed that this would be pretty fitting to do this.

However, we ran into some issues actually confirming our potential-winner pool and also determining a time to do the rolling, which resulted in us, well, not rolling last week.

Taking a gander at chat room activity levels, it seems liveliest somewhere in the later parts of today, so I'm figuring that rather than push this off for any more days, we'll look at rolling some time this evening. I will be waiting in [the RPG General Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), which is where the rolling will take place. Currently, just to pull a number out of thin air, <strike>18:00 EDT</strike>, but I'll be happy to hold it earlier or later if people think there's a much better timing (just leave a comment~).

<strike>UPDATE: Looking at 19:00 EDT after a quick conference with all of a handful of people in chat.</strike>

**UPDATE THE SECOND**: We're looking at **20:00 EDT**. That would be at **midnight in UTC**, at the break of Tuesday.

Comment: An hour later would be better for me, and I know 1800 is not good for waxeagle. I'll poke people in the chat and see what we can come up with.

Comment: Are the final results published anywhere?

Comment: @pconcepcion It's a little tucked away, but you can find the results, as well as a transcript of the rolling, [in this post](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/win-cool-site-swag-with-our-birthday-party/2959#2959).